# Official Python API for Coinbase is marked as deprecated

Tags: coinbase-api

The [official documentation](https://developers.coinbase.com/docs/wallet/client-libraries) of the Coinbase API points to [coinbase](https://github.com/coinbase/coinbase-python) as the official Python client. However, when I check that library on github, it's marked as DEPRECATED. Is there another Python client I should be using? Are there issues with this one that I should be wary of?